# How to withdrawal ether from smart contract to adress

Tags: solidity

I'm deployed a crowdsale contract and how to withdrawal ether form contract to my account

Answer (score 1):

The contract has to support functionality to withdraw Ether from it. If there is no such functionality, the Ether sent to the contract is lost forever.

IF you're still coding the contract (or will make a new one), you can add a function something like this to withdraw:

```
function withdraw() public {
    msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

Please not that the above code is very insecure and only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Yes I'm already add this but how to withdrawal where is withdrawal option

Comment: If your contract has a function like that, you can just call the function and it will send all the contract's Ether to the sender (you)

Comment: How to call function

Comment: https://bitfalls.com/2018/04/08/how-to-call-ethereum-smart-contract-functions/